# How to round "correctly" (to certain level of accuracy)

Tags: arithmetic

Say I have the number `0.73992` and I'm rounding to 3 decimal places. My instinct would be to write `0.740 (3dp)`. But surely that implies that it is *exactly* `0.740`. The only other alternatives are to write `0.7399 (4dp)` or `0.74`, neither of which are to the requested accuracy.

I'm sure there's a nice definitive answer out there, I just can't seem to find it :/

Comment: What's the difference between 0.74 and 0.740?

Comment: None mathematically of course, but it seems like writing 0.740 is guaranteeing that the number rounds to 0.740 (eg could be 0.7401)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it was 0.11488 you would round to 0.115, and it does not implies that it is exactly 0.115. I think you just confused because the rounded number ended on 0. So, in your example, you should write 0.740.

Answer (score 0):

.0740 would be the answer. Since you're adding the 0 at the end it implies that you have an accuracy to the third decimal place.